# Changing text of copy&paste buttons

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I would like to localize my app but I can't figure how to change text in copy and paste and other other buttons. I tried to google but that is way too much irrelevant info about iphone copy/paste :/

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, setting "Localization native development region" inside .plist file to preffered language seems to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you use the system-supplied controls, the localization is handled for you by Apple, as it is for other items, like Edit or Done buttons in the table views.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I noticed that some applications somehow overrides iphone language settings and even if I have set language to English application has those texts in French